# Is this Normal?, Nikon 24mm pc-e shift knob wobble

Tags: lens, nikon

I hope somebody can help me.
I have just bought a Nikon 24mm pc-e lens that was delivered to me. It was packaged badly leaving two sides of the lens with just a single piece of cardboard for protection. I think its weight was sitting on the tilt knob for its journey to me.
I have not used this lens before but It feels to me the large tilt knob is quite loose. I’m wondering if it has been damaged in transit.
I noticed it was pulled out a few mm when I opened it and it wiggles a lot from side to side. More than what I would think it should.
It pushed in after a little awhile but still seems wobbly compared to the shift knob.
Does anybody know if this movement is normal ?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks
https://youtu.be/OWuUfU4aX4M

Comment: Does the lens even tilt when you turn the knob?

Answer (score 3):

That is not normal. None of the knobs on my 24mm PC-E pull out or wobble like that, and they are not meant to.